# how to find the two vectors, with known length, if summing them will align with another vector?

Tags: vectors

I want to find 2 vectors, $v_x$ and $v_y$

with known length of each vector, $|v_x|$ and $|v_y|$ are both known

and summing them will align with another known vector $v_z$

which means $$v_x + v_y = kv_a$$ where k can be arbitrary scalar.

how to solve it?

I know there may be infinite possible solutions, so I think I will need a variable to control the final solution.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What about letting $\mathbf v_x$ be $|\mathbf v_x| \cdot \dfrac{\mathbf v_a}{|\mathbf v_a|}$, and similarly for $\mathbf v_y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometrically:

1. Pick any point $P$ on the line given by $v_a$ and *inside* the circle of radius $|v_x|+|v_y|$  around the origin $O$.
2. Draw the circle of radius $|v_x|$ around $O$ and the circle of radius $|v_y|$ arouns $P$
3. By choice of $P$, these two circles intersect. Let $Q$ be one of the points of intersection and let $v_x=\vec{OQ}$ and $v_b=\vec{QP}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are given $\vec a, \vec b$ their combination should align with $\vec c$, then you requrie:
$\vec a+ p\vec b= k \vec c~~~~(1)$
Dot this equation with $\vec a$ and then with $\vec b$ to get
$$a^2+p (\vec a. \vec b)=k (\vec a. \vec c)~~~(2)$$
and $$\vec a. \vec b+p b^2=k (\vec b. \vec c)~~~(3)$$
These are two simple simultaneous equation,solve
them to get $p,k$,